# change random number when echo

Tags: php, session, random

i have a problem with [rand](/questions/tagged/rand) function in [php](/questions/tagged/php). i set random number on a **$_SESSION** and in other place echo this. but *every time* i **echo $_SESSION**, value on it is changed.
my code in page1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['y'] = rand(1,100);
echo $_SESSION['y'];
```

and in other page2 i write this:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['y'];
```

how can i solve it?

note that page2 is appended with ajax to page1 when clicking on a button.

Comment: you mean that you're only refreshing page2, and $_SESSION['y'] change on every refresh ? are u sure page1 script is not included in page2 script ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are including page 1 on page 2.

**Option 1**

Do not include page 1 on page 2.

**Option 2**

Check to see if the random number exists before setting it.

```
session_start();
if (! isset($_SESSION['y'])) {
    $_SESSION['y'] = rand(1,100);
}
echo $_SESSION['y'];
```